# 'No Relay Access Allowed' in Swift Mailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I recently transferred my server to VPS & now email function doesn't work for external emails.
Following are the settings I'm using:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('ns1.example.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername('testing@example.com')
  ->setPassword('password');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

And the error that I'm getting is this:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:
host dedrelay.where.example.net [XX.XXX.XXX.XX]: 554
m1plded02-01.prod.mesa1.example.net : DED : 
gWqF1p02c0cB4sG01 : DED : ESMTP
No Relay Access Allowed From XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I've tried `telnet` & response is ok. I've tried following:

```
telnet ns1.example.com 465
```

Response was:

```
connected to xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

I'm also not able to configure my desktop email client. Can anyone tell a solution? Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm not even able to send an email through server's webmail. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried `telnet ns1.example.com 465` and it connected. This shows the SMTP server is up and running and your computer can reach it. But this is not all you need.

The error message `No Relay Access Allowed From 123.123.123.123` means the SMTP server is configured to not accept emails from this IP address for relay, i.e. emails that needs to be passed to another server for delivery.

This is an anti-abuse measure and it means the SMTP server is configured correctly.

There is nothing wrong with your `SwiftMailer` configuration. Any email client (including the desktop client, as you said) you use, the answer is the same.

You need to contact the system administrator of the SMTP server and ask them to allow your IP address to use their SMTP server as relay. If they are your ISP it's also possible that the server allows relay only after authentication: you have an username/password pair (that you use to read the emails, f.e.) and you need to use it in order to send emails through their SMTP server. But this is only a supposition (this is how it usually works); you have to ask them to know for sure.